# WebRTC STUN and TURN servers in C#

Tags: c#, webrtc, stun, turn

My question today is how to develop stun and turn servers for webrtc peer-to-peer application in c# is there any library supports this, I can't find any example or resource to obtain this.

Please help me with this because it took me too much time searching with no luck.
I tried OfficeSip and didn't work also I tried coturn over cygwin but didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there's any STUN/TURN server or library implemented in C#.

The ones that I know of are

- [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn)
- [PJNATH](http://www.pjsip.org/pjnath/docs/html/)
- [STUNTMAN](http://www.stunprotocol.org/)
- [go-stun](https://github.com/pixelbender/go-stun)
- [ReTurn](https://www.resiprocate.org/ReTurn_Overview)
- [turnover](https://github.com/balena/turnover)

On the coturn page you can see a list of all the RFC that has to be implemented.

Frankly, I would not commit to such a huge task of implementing a TURN/STUN server. If you need one that works in Windows, and none of these work, you can try to run it in a VM or something like Docker.